# X11 session fails to start on arm64 Ubuntu 23.10 on Raspberry Pi 5

Tags: xorg, raspberrypi, 23.10

Ubuntu 23.10 arm64 has been working great on the Raspberry Pi 5 with Wayland. I would like to disable Wayland and use X11 session instead, as there are some features of Citrix that do not work in Wayland, so I attempted to disable Wayland by setting `WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`. This approach has worked well on Ubuntu 22.04 on the Raspberry Pi 4, however on 23.10 on the Raspberry 5, the X11 session fails to start: I just end up with a blinking cursor on the screen. Are there other steps that are required to get X11 working on Ubuntu 23.10 on the raspi5?

**Update 1**

Running startx from the console (via ssh) gives the following output:

```
jacob@jacob-raspi5:~$ startx
xauth:  file /home/jacob/.Xauthority does not exist

/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console.
```

Please see the output of /var/log/Xorg.*.log below:

Xorg.0.log:

```
    [    30.342] (--) Log file renamed from "/var/log/Xorg.pid-1178.log" to "/var/log/Xorg.0.log"
[    30.342] 
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.7
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    30.342] Current Operating System: Linux jacob-raspi5 6.5.0-1005-raspi #7-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun Oct  8 08:06:18 UTC 2023 aarch64
[    30.342] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 pci=pcie_bus_safe snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1  smsc95xx.macaddr=D8:3A:DD:E9:CD:51 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3fc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  zswap.enabled=1 zswap.zpool=z3fold zswap.compressor=zstd multipath=off dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 rootwait fixrtc quiet splash
[    30.343] xorg-server 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    30.343] Current version of pixman: 0.42.2
[    30.343]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    30.343] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    30.343] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Jan 31 22:53:21 2024
[    30.343] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    30.343] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    30.343] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    30.343] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    30.343] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    30.343] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    30.343] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    30.343] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    30.343] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    30.343] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    30.344] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    30.344] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    30.344]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    30.344] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    30.344]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    30.344] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    30.344]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    30.344] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    30.344]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    30.344] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    30.344]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    30.344] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    30.344] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    30.344] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    30.344] (II) Loader magic: 0xaaaac3560010
[    30.344] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    30.344]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    30.344]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[    30.344]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[    30.344]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    30.345] (++) using VT number 1

[    30.347] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/c6
[    30.350] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    30.350] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/platform/axi/1002000000.v3d/drm/card0
[    30.351] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 14 paused 0
[    30.352] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    30.352] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/platform/axi/axi:gpu/drm/card1
[    30.353] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card1 226:1 fd 15 paused 0
[    30.354] (II) no primary bus or device found
[    30.354]    falling back to /sys/devices/platform/axi/1002000000.v3d/drm/card0
[    30.354] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    30.354] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    30.355] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    30.355]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 1.0.0
[    30.355]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    30.356] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[    30.356] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[    30.356] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    30.356] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    30.356] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    30.356] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    30.356]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 1.21.1
[    30.356]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    30.356]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[    30.356] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    30.356] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    30.356] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    30.356]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.5.0
[    30.356]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    30.356]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[    30.356] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    30.356] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    30.357] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    30.357] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    30.357] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    30.357] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    30.357] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    30.357] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    30.357]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 0.0.2
[    30.357]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[    30.357] (II) FBDEV(0): using default device
[    30.357] (II) modeset(G0): using drv /dev/dri/card1
[    30.357] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[    30.357] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    30.357] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[    30.357] (EE) 
[    30.357] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    30.357] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    30.357] (EE) 
[    30.370] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

**Update 2**

Please see the output of `sudo lshw -c display` below:

```
jacob@jacob-raspi5:~$ sudo lshw -c display
  *-graphics                
       product: vc4drmfb
       physical id: a
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=16 resolution=1920,1080
```

***Update 3***

Please see the result of running `startx <>/dev/tty1 >&0 2>&0`

[image: result of running startx <>/dev/tty1 >&0 2>&0]

Comment: Does `startx` (arguments might be required) in TTY work? After doing that, what are the errors on the console and in `/var/log/Xorg.*.log`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I don't get a prompt, just a blinking cursor on the upper left corner, so not sure if there's a way to try to run startx or read the logs. ACPI does work though - I can press the power button and it initiates shutdown. Maybe I need to set up ssh server and try to login from another machine. I will try this and follow up.

Comment: Hi @DanielT I posted the relevant logs in the question above. I would appreciate any insight you could share on this. Thanks.

Comment: I think the last couple of lines are the important ones: [    30.357] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[    30.357] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    30.357] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[    30.357] (EE)

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo lshw -c display` to your question

Comment: "(via ssh)": No, that won't work. How is X supposed to know which TTY it should start up on? If you want to risk it, you can sudo -i, stop and disable the getty on TTY1, then `startx <>/dev/tty1 >&0 2>&0`, then switch to that TTY

Comment: @Raffa I have added it. Thanks so much.

Comment: @DanielT I have post a photo of the output. Thank you!

Comment: This: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=358853 seems to be related … and the issue  seems to be related to a kernel driver and present in some kernel versions but not others.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Raffa for pointing me in the right direction in the comment to the OP above.

I found the solution here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/+bug/2044718/comments/2

Just install gldriver-test_0.15 from Debian repo here:

https://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/g/gldriver-test/gldriver-test_0.15_all.deb

Then:

```
sudo apt install raspi-config 
sudo dpkg -i gldriver-test_0.15_all.deb
```

Then edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and disable wayland.

Reboot, and X should start as expected.

Also, note that the Gnome UI feels noticeably slower under X than it does in Wayland. But this is fine for my application.